# Unit testing HttpClientModule in Angular 4.3: undefined return value from HttpTestingController.expectOne(url)

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to understand how to use the mocking functionality provided as part of the new `HttpClientModule`. My test code matches what's shown in the existing documentation almost exactly. However, the doc example is not complete - for example, at a minimum the import statement for `TestBad` and `inject` is missing. I assume the same is true of `HttpClient` from @angular/common/http. My test code adds these.

This test fails, as `req` ends up being undefined after the `httpMock.expectOne` call. I'd appreciate any insight into why that might be.

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('HttpClientTestingModule', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
    providers: [ HttpClient, HttpTestingController]
  }));

  it('expects a GET request', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], (http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
    http
      .get('/data')
      .subscribe(data => expect(data['name']).toEqual('Test Data'));

    const req = httpMock.expectOne('/data');
    expect(req).toBeDefined();
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush({name: 'Test Data'});
    httpMock.verify();
  }));
});
```

Comment: @MathijsSegers, if the call to `httpMock.expectOne` were to somehow fail, `req` will be undefined. It's not critical here, mostly just habit on my part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I don't understand why this is the case, I got it working, by removing the following from `TestBed.configureTestingModule`:

`providers: [HttpClient, HttpTestingController]`

I welcome any insight into why I need to add my own services to `providers` collection, but not `HttpClient, HttpTestingController`.

Comment: As was explained to me on the [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18499#issuecomment-320434640) I opened on this, there's no need to explicitly provide `HttpClient` & `HttpTestingController` since they're already provided by `HttpClientTestingModule`.

Comment: @Bill, I rejected your edit for a couple of reasons: 

* My original answer explained _what_ the fix was, even though I didn't understand _why_ at the time. 
* Once I figured out why, I added an explanation in a comment. This comment (above) is essentially the same as your edit, so the edit seems unnecessary. 
* Editing an answer that's more than a year old feels a bit like hunting for points.

Comment: No problem, @StuartUpdegrave. I actually came across your answer when I was updating some unit tests to use HttpTestingController instead of the deprecated MockBackend. I was running into the same problem, and your answer was helpful (which is why I upvoted it). SO incentivizes users to edit (even old posts) by giving points, to keep quality Q/A's. In keeping with the third bullet in stackoverflow.com/help/editing - I thought the edit would be helpful. All that being said, it's no problem if you don't feel like it was a good edit. :)

Comment: Comments are meant to be temporary, so editing the post to include the correct information is the way to go. It's not about hunting for points, it's about putting the answer in the answer and making it as complete and correct as possible.