# Unit testing http service on Angular 5

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm pretty confused about how to test a data service, there's just way too many possibilities and it's overwhelming.

I have this simple service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getData<T>(path: string): Observable<T> {
    return this._http.get<T>(path);
  }

}
```

I want to test that calling `getData<number>` will, infact, return a data type of `number`.

The [angular testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing)  frustratingly shows several ways (use testbed, use beforeEach, use jasmine without testBed) and I've tried all of them but not with much success.

How do I do this please? I have so far failed to even get as far as calling the `getData`. I want to be able to mock the Http, emit mock return values (like in `jasmine.spy.and.returnValue(mockData)`) and verify that dataService is OK

I've got this in my `data.service.spec.ts`:

```
describe('DataService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [
        DataService,
        HttpClient
      ]
    });

  });

  // This was auto generated, and works
  it('should be created', inject([DataService], (service: DataService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  // I added this, but doesn't work
  describe('When getData() is called', () => {

    it('should return an observable of type T', inject([DataService], (service: DataService) => {

      service.getData<number>('mock-url')
        .subscribe(data => {
          expect(typeof(data)).toBe('number');
        });

    }));

  });

});
```

When I say it doesn't work... the second test passes! but it shouldn't. I can see the real request go out on dev console to the (invalid) url, and that errors out as expected, but the test just passes...

So I guess, my question is simply, in Angular 5, how do I mock my backend service and unit test it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to test it like this using flush method

```
 inject(
  [HttpTestingController, DataService],
  (httpMock: HttpTestingController, service: DataService) =>{
     const mockResponse = 5;
     const mock-url = '...';

     service.getData<number>('mock-url').subscribe(data => {
        expect(data).toEqual(mockResponse);
         expect(typeof(data)).toBe('number');
    });

    const mockRequest = httpMock.expectOne((req: HttpRequest<any>) => req.url === mock-url); //get your request here

    expect(mockRequest.request.method).toBe('GET');

    mockRequest.flush(mockResponse);
   })
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for that. I get a `httpMock.expectOne is not a function` error. Do I need to initialise it before calling?

Comment: did you add HttpClientTestingModule in your TestBed.configureTestingModule ?

Comment: Yup! it's added into the providers array!

Comment: Hi, this started working after I *removed* `HttpClient, HttpTestingController` from providers. Found from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45482697/435867