# Test API calls in service class with Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, karma-runner

I am not an expert when it comes to Angular testing, and I am having troubles in writing the correct test class for the following snippet of code:

```
checkAuth(user: User): Observable<boolean> {
    const endpoint = `${environment.apiHost}/${environment.apiUrl}/${environment.apiVersion}/user`;
    return this.httpClient.post<ApiResponse>(endpoint, user).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (response.status === ApiResponseStatus.OK) {
          const authUser = response.payload as User;
          this._currentUserSubject.next(authUser);
          this._isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
          return true;
        } else {
          this._currentUserSubject.next({});
          this._isAuthenticatedSubject.next(false);
          return false;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

As you can see, not only the method calls an external API (which could not be available at the time of running the test), but I should also provide the testing part for all response mapping cases after the Observable object is returned.

Would you mind giving me an example on how I should create the "spec.ts" class for this?

Thank you.

Alessio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unit testing http service on Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582680/unit-testing-http-service-on-angular-5)

Comment: Not completely... First of all, while testing the original service, the back-end could not be available, hence the call could not be compared with the TestController one. Second, this post doesn't answer the part where I re-map the response of the API, which shall be tested as well.